# I can't use javascript imports with in my react-typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

I am trying to add a google login feature with firebase. I am using react hooks and typescript. I cant seem to use the `StyledFirebaseAuth` module. when i try to render it, it gives this error

```
JSX element type 'StyledFirebaseAuth' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'StyledFirebaseAuth' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.
```

I have tried checking my tsconfig for any setting that could be causing this

This is my Import

`import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';`

when i try to render

```
<StyledFirebaseAuth
 uiConfig={uiConfig}
 firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
 />
```

i get this error

```
JSX element type 'StyledFirebaseAuth' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'StyledFirebaseAuth' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.
```

Comment: pls post the code of your `StyledFirebaseAuth`

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out thanks. All i had to do was delete my package-lock.json